# Engine only runs on full choke

Tags: ford, carburetor, choke, thunderbird

Ford 390 Autolite carburetter
Starts ok but only runs on full choke the two fuel needles don’t seem to make a difference. ( they used to be ok before cleaning).

This carburettor did work ok, but I decided to clean it, float levels are good, I’ve checked for vacuum leaks, around the engine, nothing done on actual motor  other than removing and replacing the carb had been done,
The only thing I noticed was that when I pressed the accelerator pump handle one ONE Venturi  squirted fuel, I’m not sure if both should?
So no leaks, no fuel pin changes when engine running and the choke had to be full on I’ve also noticed that has the engine gets warm the choke doesn’t alter ??
Help
Neil be

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! What vehicle are we talking about (year/model ... I know it's a Ford and assume it's a 390ci engine).

Comment: It’s a 1963 tbird with sutolite 4100 it was running ok? But I decided to check float level etc took it off blow cleaned inside the only thing I may have done wrong I put some gasket maker on the proper gasket, could it be that the air inside is far too much after that?

Comment: It not running unless the choke is closed is an indication your idle jets/passages aren't flowing fuel. Also, that you only have fuel coming through on one venturi is also an indication fuel isn't flowing there (should be on both). Fuel passages are plugged and not letting fuel through. What might have cause it, who knows. [Here's something which might help you.](https://www.carburetor-parts.com/assets/manuals/4100_eBook.pdf) Unfortunately I don't have enough experience with Autolite carbs to be of much more help.